# Logic: Proving a Negated Disjunction is a Conjunction of Negations

Tags: logic, advice

~ = Not

V = Disjunction

& = Conjunction

A and B are stand ins for more complex formula but I know how to derive the whole derivation if I just had their negations.
So I know that ~(A V B) = ~A & ~B, but I don't know how to prove that.
Proofs I see online basically say "Assume A, or Assume B" but I'm doing work on a logic lab that doesn't let me just assume them in a negated disjunction. My logic lab also doesn't just let me use DeM. I also don't have (~A & ~B) as a goal, so I cant just negate that with negation elimination.
I have another formula that can create the Falsum if I can derive ~A & ~B.

Assume: ~(A V B)

Goal: Falsum

Original Goal:(A V B)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do this without making assumptions is to use a Hilbert system that contains axioms for disjunction and conjunction. Here’s how I’d do it:

1. ~A->(~B->(~A&~B))  (& Intro)
2. A->(AvB)           (v Intro Left)
3. B->(AvB)           (v Intro Right)
4. ~(AvB)->~A         (2, Transposition)
5. ~(AvB)->~B         (3, Transposition)
6. (~(AvB)->(~B->(~A&~B)))->

   ((~(AvB)->~B)->(~(AvB)->(~A&~B)))    (axiom 2)
7. ~(AvB)->(~B->(~A&~B))  (1,4 HS)
8. (~(AvB)->~B)->(~(AvB)->(~A&~B)) (6,7 MP)
9. ~(AvB)->(~A&~B)  (5,8 MP)

Answer (score 0):

$\lnot (a \lor b) \equiv \lnot(\lnot a \implies b) \equiv \lnot a\land \lnot b$. You can always show it via an arb. truth table, too.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What specific rules could I use to make these inferences? Like how would I make the leap of ¬(a∨b)≡¬(¬a⟹b)?

Comment: That's what disjunction means, you can also show it with a direct proof assume $a \lor b$ assume $\lnot a$ you can deduce  $b$ from $\lnot a, (a\lor b)$ and conclude $\lnot a\implies b$